# Keeping a variable when referring to a method multiple times

Tags: java, string, random, methods, return

I need this to print out "N1" and then "N2" in random order. My problem is I don't know how to keep the values (num, and num2) so it doesn't print the same number twice. I don't know how to keep a value for the next time the method is used. Any help is apprectiated :)

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(random());
        System.out.println(random());
    }
    public static String random() {
        Random rgen = new Random();
        int rNumber;
        int num = 0, num2 = 0;

        do {
            rNumber = rgen.nextInt(2) + 1;
        } while ((rNumber == 1 && num == 1) || (rNumber == 2 && num2 == 1));

        if (rNumber == 1) {
            num = 1;
            return "N1";
        }
        else if (rNumber == 2) {
                num2 = 1;
            return "N2";
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not create those variables as `instance variables`?

Comment: It's not random if it can't print the same number twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that you want to preserve the values of `num` and `num2`.  
Remove their declarations from `random()`, and put these at the class level, before `main()`:

```
private static int num = 0;
private static int num2 = 0;
```

otherwise this loop:

```
do {
    rNumber = rgen.nextInt(2) + 1;
} while ((rNumber == 1 && num == 1) || (rNumber == 2 && num2 == 1));
```

does not make sense, since the condition:

```
((rNumber == 1 && num == 1) || (rNumber == 2 && num2 == 1))
```

would always be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

To store something beyond a functions scope, either return it an pass it to the next call or use a static variable:

```
public class Testing {
    public static int store = 0;
    /* your code*/
}
```

This variable can be accessed just like any other variable, but doesn't loose its value. ever. It can only be changed.

But a much simpler solution would be:

```
public static void random() {
    System.out.println(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "N1\nN2" : "N2\nN1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this job you have to create two global variables num1 and num2 (Variables declared outside the scope of any function). Since your random() function is static so it is preferable that you use static global variable. Global variable do not get reset and retain their value until a function modifies their values.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition here `} while ((rNumber == 1 && num == 1) || (rNumber == 2 && num2 == 1));` is always false. You haven't assigned num and num1 any new value after initialization.
Also, maybe you wanted something like this?

```
package com.testing;
import java.util.Random;
public class Testing {
    private static int num = 1, num2 = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i =0; i < 30; i++) {
            System.out.println(random());
        }
    }

    public static String random() {
        Random rgen = new Random();
        int rNumber = rgen.nextInt(2) + 1;
        if (rNumber == 1) return "N1";
        else if (rNumber == 2) return "N2";
        else return null;
    }
}
```